# How to Getting a List from MS Sql Server Using Java

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, resultset

I have a problem, I cannot get my list from MS SQL Server Database.

This is my code:

```
public List<Location> showLocations(String nmlocation) {
    List<Location> location = new ArrayList<Location>();
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT deskripsi FROM T_Place WHERE ID_Place='%" + nmlocation + "%'";
        PreparedStatement statement = (PreparedStatement) dm.logON().prepareStatement(sql);
        boolean result = statement.execute();
        if (result) {
            ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet();
            int i = 0;
            while (rs.next()) 
            {
                Location loc = new Location(rs.getString("deskripsi"));
                System.out.println(loc);
                location.add(loc);
                i++;
            }
            rs.close();
        }


     } catch (SQLException sqle) {
      System.out.println("Error on Listing Location Data showLocation Status : " + sqle.getSQLState()
                + " \n Error Message : " + sqle.getMessage()
                + " \n Error State : " + sqle.toString());
    }
    return location;
}
```

But it shows empty resultset. How to fix it? thanks in advance.

Comment: Looking at your query, it looks a little bit like you are trying to do a wild card query. If this is the case you should use "ID_Place like %..." instead.

Comment: @heldt hi,i need to showing a result set from a specific query. Example, i need to show specific query like "BIKE" from the database. Any suggestion?

Comment: a) remove the % characters and b) when you use a preparedstatement don't inject values into the query yourself, read an article or the javadoc on preparedstatement to learn how to properly use it using parameters.